# Как был бы реализован данный код в java 7?

Tags: java

Разбираюсь в нововведениях в Java 8 и не могу понять, как был бы написан данный код в java 7.

```
class Something {
        String startsWith(String s) {
            return String.valueOf(s.charAt(0));
        }
    }
```

...

```
Something something = new Something();
Converter<String, String> converter = something::startsWith;
String converted = converter.convert("Java");
System.out.println(converted);    // "J"
```

Набросал что-то такое:

```
class Something implements Converter {
    String startsWith(String s) {
        return String.valueOf(s.charAt(0));
    }
    public String convert(String s){
        return startsWith(s);
    }
}
```

...

```
Something something = new Something();
Converter<String, String> converter = new Something();

String converted = converter.convert("Java");
System.out.println(converted);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как в Java 7 невозможно (если не использовать Reflections API) вызвать произвольный метод класса по имени, ваша реализация верна. Если не принимать во внимание то, что класс `Something` реализует непараметризованный интерфейс `Converter`, а в коде вы используете ссылку на параметризованный интерфейс. Скорее всего, вы имели ввиду что-то вроде этого:

```
interface Converter<In, Out> {
    Out convert(In value);
}

class Something implements Converter<String, String> {
    String startsWith(String s) {
        return s.charAt(0);
    }

    String convert(String s) {
        return startsWith(s);
    }
}

Converter<String, String> converter = new Something();
System.out.println(converter.convert("Java"));
```

Метод `startsWith` класса `Something` можно было и не выделять как отдельный, а реализовать его в методе `convert`, если только вы не планировали портировать этот класс на Java 8 и использовать ссылку на этот метод.

Если же вам хочется хардкора, то можно использовать Reflections API для поиска метода по имени и списку аргументов, однако, это далеко не лучший вариант как в плане производительности, так и в плане надёжности кода.

Comment: Да, про джнерики забыл, а выделил StartsWith в отдельный метод на тот случай если бы логика была более сложной. Спасибо